# What is the best way to export millions of record from Maria db table to excel?

Tags: mysql, .net, export-to-excel

I have a table in Maris db that may contain a lot of record, and I want to export these records to excel.
I thought using DataReader instead of DataTable so I wouldn't lock the table ro get my db stuck.
Is this the appropriate approach or is there a better one ?

Comment: Found this article: [Export very large data to Excel file](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659666/Export-very-large-data-to-Excel-file)
Hope this is the right way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Using a third party library is the right way. Try also [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com). Find the fastest one.

Here you can find some guidelines about [exporting large data to Excel file](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/tips-and-tricks/export-large-excel-file.html).